# How can I disable automatic string detection in VS2015?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VB.NET, and my code contains a lot of strings that very often have double quotes inside of them. My problem is that as I'm fixing the string to escape double quotes (replacing every '"' with '""' inside of the string) it messes with the proceeding code, temporarily assuming everything is a string (since the double quotes don't match up) and completely messing up the formatting of other strings. It assumes that the start of a following string is the end of the current string which causes the actual string to be interpreted and formatted as code, which I have to go back and fix (since it adds spaces and other formatting characters that shouldn't actually be there).

Is there any way to disable this behavior? I didn't have the same problem in VS2013. I've been looking under Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

**Additional Information:** I can just modify the strings in a separate text document to escape all of the double-quotes (which is what I've resorted to for now), but in VS2013 I could easily just copy/paste the strings directly into my code without it messing up proceeding strings by temporarily interpreting them as code due to the uneven count of double-quotes.

This behavior is especially problematic when manually adding double-quotes within strings, because if you don't escape them quickly enough (or make a brief typo when doing so), you get the same issue.

You might notice that for other languages, such as C++, writing a string on one line (even with an uneven number of double-quotes) does not affect proceeding lines. Having this same behavior for VB would be great, assuming that there's some setting to enable it.

Comment: would using XML literals be an option? I can provide sample code in an answer if it will.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its an inconvenience.

What I usually do is put some non-used character (e.g. some unused symbol on keyboard, or Alt+{some number}) instead of double quotes. When I'm done building my string whatever way I want, I just finalize it with either bringing up the `Find and Replace` box and replace that character with two double-quotes. Or just put a `REPLACE` statement immediately following it, replacing that character with `Chr(34)`.

Answer (score -2):

Instead use Chr(34), or if you end up repeating strings at all, store them as a [resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6z7a1dy(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: That's majorly inconvenient to do for large strings containing many, many (inconsistently-placed) double-quotes, and rarely do I end up repeating strings. I'm mostly dealing with parsing out specific values from HTML documents of inconsistent layout/style (by looking for document-specific substrings).

Comment: Is Find/Replace really that difficult though?  It would be nice if the feature you're looking for existed, but AFAIK it doesn't, and you're the first person I've ever encountered asking for it, rather than just using Chr(34), or string resources, both viable, even if undesirable, alternatives.  By all means if you find something better, throw it up as an answer and I'll up vote if it fits your requirements better.  But this idea of down-voting folks and saying how 'majorly inconvenient' their factually accurate answers are is going to be the death of this site.

Comment: FYI, I didn't down-vote your answer. This is primarily an issue of convenience, as I can easily come up with millions of inconvenient solutions; the problem is finding something that works as well as VS2013 string-handling did (especially when it comes to pasting strings directly into the code, in which case I run into the same problem with the Chr(34) "solution"). I apologize if that was unclear. You might notice that for other languages, such as C++, it doesn't attempt to do any formatting beyond the line you're currently working with. If that's impossible with VS2015, so be it.

Comment: My apologies Squidy, didn't mean to suggest you did. And it's not the downvotes that bother me so much as the unwillingness to accept an answer you (SO/internet in general, not you specifically) don't like, or that you think doesn't answer the question asked. Yes, I should have been more direct in saying in my answer that what you're asking is just not possible in the latest version of VS, my bad.   Back to your original question:  Have you tried using multi-line strings (Not certain, but I believe VB14 now supports this in VS2015) or perhaps using String.Format with {n} params?